# Run a program with data from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I previously created a VBA program that launched the form from a command button.  Sheet 1 was the command button and Sheet 2 was the data that the program referenced.  I want to put the data into a separate workbook so that I can put it in a shared drive that can be run on other machines, as well as giving me the option to update the data in the workbook (all separate from the original program).  I also think this would make the program faster and much more lightweight, so it doesn't have to open up all the data in Sheet 2 along with it.  How could I open the data workbook in the background and be able to reference it in my code?

Comment: `workbook.open` with screenupdating=false??

Comment: If you really want it even more in the background you can open it in another Excel instance and set the `Excel.Application.Visible = False` *or actually do not set it to `True`, I think it opens as False by default when initialized via VBA.*